# select from JSON_TABLE where the json is a flat array

Tags: ibm-midrange

How to select from JSON_TABLE where the json is a flat array ?

here is the SQL that builds a table with some JSON text in `data` and `flat` columns:

```
create table mytest (id int, data varchar(3276),
       flat  varchar(3000)                      
     )                                          

insert into mytest values(1, '{"a":[1,2,3]}', '[8,9,10]')
```

JSON_TABLE returns the items in the array from the column that contains a JSON object:

```
select m.id, jt.*                                    
from mytest m, JSON_TABLE(m.data, '$.a[*]' COLUMNS ( 
          val int    path '$'                        
   )) jt
```

But I get no rows when I run a similar query against the column that contains a JSON flat array:

```
select m.id, jt.*                                    
from mytest m, JSON_TABLE(m.flat, '$.[*]' COLUMNS (  
          val int    path '$'                        
   )) jt
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the `.` on the path...it's `'$[*]'` not `'$.[*]'`

```
select m.id, jt.*                                    
from mytest m, JSON_TABLE(m.flat, '$[*]' COLUMNS (  
          val int    path '$'                        
   )) jt
```